# Mac Two Screens

Tags: display, macos

I have my MacBook Pro hooked up to a big monitor. I know that I can do something where the monitors are mirrored, or the monitors are virtually "side by side."

Can I have my MacBook Pro on one "Desktop 1" (like the desktops you press F3 to see) and my monitor on Desktop 2? That way, I would be able to do the three finger mouse swipe to change between screens. Is that possible in the current Mac OS?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is: `System preferences > Mission control > [x] Displays have separate spaces`

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a way to get the two screens to display two different "desktops" as you describe them.

However, do you not have effectively the same thing when you arrange the two screens "side-by-side" (or top-and-bottom, or whatever geometry you set in the "System Preferences" -> "Displays" -> "Arrangement" control)? Using one finger to move the mouse from one display to the othe brings along a dock and a menu bar, no? What more could you want?